# presenting same image in all orientations in fullscreen

Tags: iphone, orientation, imageview

I was just wondering how can I set up a gallery in landscape and portrait mode, and show the images as normal in both modes (not stretched or squashed). The only way I can think of is having the same image in both sizes so it can be shown the one that suits the orientation. This idea appears "dumb" to me so if someone knows a better way to set an image view in all orientations please give me some advices

Comment: May be autoresizesSubviews property on your main view can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Landscape and portrait are different aspect ratios.  If you don't want to stretch or squash the images, you can either crop the image or letterbox it.

Cropping is where you don't show the entire image, for instance an image that covers the entire screen in portrait would have the top and bottom removed.

Letterboxing is where the entire image is shown, but with a solid colour surrounding the image.  For instance, a landscape image shown in portrait would have black areas above and below the image.

It's relatively easy to do the above on the iPhone by selecting the correct content mode options in Interface Builder.

You can also supply different images as you describe, but that would just mean that you'd be cropping or letter boxing manually.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the `contentMode` property of your image view (or any `UIView` subclass, for that matter). Set it to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`, which will size the content of the image view to fill as much of it as possible without distorting the aspect ratio or clipping anything. In this case, just set the image view to be as large as possible, and the content mode will handle the rest.